# Auto move data to archive if is changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in MySQL. It's posible to auto move rows from table1 to table2 if status is 1?

```
Table1 
ID|Ticket|Status
1|23235|0
2|43434|0

Table2
ID|Ticket|Status|Solved-date
1|23223|1|01.02.2016
2|43433|1|01.02.2016
```

Now if in Table1, on ID1 status is changed to 1, to automaticaly move to Table2 by SQL server.

I don't need a PHP solution, to delete from Table 1 and Insert to Table2.

Comment: You can use after update/insert trigger to delete the row and insert it to the other table

Comment: See mysql event schedulers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html